# Elementary geometry problem.

Tags: geometry

$ABC$ is a right-angled triangle with right angle at $B$. $D$ is a point on $AC$ such that angle $ABD = 45^{\circ}$. If $AC = 6$ cm and $AD = 2$ cm then $AB$ is?

I'm not able to proceed further from $AB^2+BC^2=36.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $E$ on $AB$ and $F$ on $BC$ such that $DE\perp AB$ and $DF\perp BC$. Then $BEDF$ is a square. In particular, $DE=DF$.

$\displaystyle \frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{\frac12 (AB)(DE)}{\frac12 (BC)(DF)}=\frac{\textrm{area of }\triangle ABD}{\textrm{area of }\triangle CBD}=\frac{AD}{DC}=\frac24$.

$BC=2AB$ (this is actually angle bisector theorem) and hence $AB^2+(2AB)^2=36$.

$AB=\frac6{\sqrt{5}}\;\textrm{cm}$.

Comment: @Seyed Could you please explain why it is impossible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought $BD=2$.